# how to add multiple polyline colors in googlemaps ios sdk using swift?

Tags: ios, swift4

I have some locations given for example:- a to point b, point c to point d.

Point a to b should be drawn in red colour and point d to c should be drawn in yellow colour. This point c and point d will be moving vehicles, so it will be dynamic.

currently

```
 func initializePolylineAnnotation2(_newLocation: CLLocation)
    {
        //self.polyline.strokeColor = UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.84, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0)

        //self.polyline.strokeWidth = 5.0
           var polyline = GMSPolyline()
        let solidRed = GMSStrokeStyle.solidColor(UIColor(red:1.00, green:0.84, blue:0.00, alpha:1.0))
        polyline.spans = [GMSStyleSpan(style: solidRed)]

        polyline.map = self.mapView
        self.updateOverlay(_newLocation,polyline: polyline)
        self.updateCurrentPositionMarker(_newLocation)

    }


func updateOverlay(_ currentPosition: CLLocation,polyline : GMSPolyline)
    {

        self.path.add(currentPosition.coordinate)
        polyline.path = self.path
        if self.DBidArr.contains(self.movingChannel)
        {
            let index = self.DBidArr.index(of: self.movingChannel)

            if index! < self.pathDB.count
            {
                self.pathDB[index!].add(currentPosition.coordinate)
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28045266/how-can-draw-2-line-in-my-mapkit-with-different-color-in-swift

Comment: i was asking for google maps actually

Comment: Include sample code. How are you drawing polyline now?

Comment: i added it to original post

Comment: This is in objective c convert from objective c to swift http://ioscake.com/ios-google-sdk-map-cannot-create-dotted-polylines.html

Comment: ok i will check this. seems useful