# Custom polygon class to change stroke color

Tags: swift2

I am trying to create a custom polygon class so I can dynamically change the stroke color of polygons but I am getting an error:

```
Objective-C method 'mapView:rendererForOverlay:' provided by method 'mapView(_:rendererForOverlay:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'mapView(_:rendererForOverlay:)' in protocol 'MKMapViewDelegate'
```

Here is my implementation:

```
self.polygon = CustomPolygon(coordinates: &decodedCoordinates!, count: polygon.coordinates!.count)
self.mapView.addOverlay(self.polygon)

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, rendererForOverlay overlay: CustomPolygon) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    let polygonRenderer = MKPolygonRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    polygonRenderer.lineWidth = 3

    polygonRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor(rgba: overlay.color)

    return polygonRenderer
}
```

CustomPolygon.swift

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class CustomPolygon : MKPolygon {
    var color: String?
}
```

I am trying to follow this SO question [How to make custom MKPolyline in SWIFT with additional argument - color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26010977/how-to-make-custom-mkpolyline-in-swift-with-additional-argument-color) but for polygon not polyline.

Thanks