# Binding array is empty when accessed through Coordinator

Tags: swiftui, uikit, mkmapview, uiviewrepresentable

I am having an issue with my Coordinator. I am interacting with a MKMapView via SwiftUI. I am passing in a Binding to the UIViewRepresentable and need to access that same Binding in the Coordinator. Inside the Coordinator I determine what strokeColor to use for my polyline. When I try to access the routes Binding from my Coordinator it is always empty. When I set a breakpoint inside the `MapView` on the `updateUIView` function the binding is indeed populated.

Heres the code:

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    @Binding var routes: [RouteData]
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        
        addOverlays(mapView)
        
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ view: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        addOverlays(view)
        removeOverlays(view)
    }
    
    private func addOverlays(_ view: MKMapView) {
        for route in routes {
            for point in route.points {
                let waypoints = point.waypoints
                let polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: waypoints, count: waypoints.count)
                polyline.title = route.routeID
                view.addOverlay(polyline)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func removeOverlays(_ view: MKMapView) {
        for overlay in view.overlays {
            if let routeID = overlay.title!, routes.first(where: { $0.routeID == routeID }) == nil {
                view.removeOverlay(overlay)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
    let parent: MapView
    
    init(_ parent: MapView) {
        self.parent = parent
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        if let routePolyline = overlay as? MKPolyline {
            let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: routePolyline)
            
            // Always prints route is empty even though I set a break point inside the parents' updateUIView func and the route is populated.
            print("parents routes: \(self.parent.routes)")
            if let title = routePolyline.title, let route = self.parent.routes.first(where: { $0.routeID == title }) {
                renderer.strokeColor = UIColor(convertRGBStringToColor(color: route.route.rtclr))
            } else {
                renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
            }
            
            renderer.lineWidth = 5
            return renderer
        }
        
        return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A few mistakes

`@Binding var routes: [RouteData]` should be `let routes: [RouteData]` because you don’t change it so don’t need the write access.

`Coordinator(self)` Should be `Coordinator()`, self is an old value the Coordinator should not hang on to.

Subclass MKPolyline to add your colour properties eg https://stackoverflow.com/a/44294417/259521

`makeUIView` Should return `context.coordinator.mapView`

`addOverlays` should only add ones that are not already added. You need to essentially implement a diff in `updateUIView`.

Update is called after make so no need to add overlays in make.